# Need to show TableView sections and rows according to json data received

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, tableview

I get JSON data as follows:

```
 {
  "upcoming": [
    {
      "id": "17",
      "date": "2018/04/23 13:25",
      "title": "Team A"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "date": "2018/04/23 13:25",
      "title": "Team B"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "date": "2019/06/16 21:45",
      "title": "Team c"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to show a table view with sections according to the date key. How can I populate a table view with sections and rows accordingly?

Comment: make model of you json and use tableview delegate method to return numberOfSection and numberOfRow accordingly.

Comment: I got numberofsections by making the unique date, but confused with showing data according to the section.

Comment: As always on StackOverflow: Please show us the code you have done (probably for your delegate?) and people will be more than willing to help if you are clear about what confuses you. Abstract and vague questions have little chance to get good answers.

Comment: self.uniqueDateArr.append(self.uniqueElementsFrom(array:self.upcomingDateArray as! [String]) as AnyObject), uniqueDateArr contains dates which are not repeated, which gives tableview sections, but I'm confused about populating rows now

Answer (score -1):

Swift comes with [the amazing Codable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) built in, you should read up on it. This will easily allow you to understand what is going on in this Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
 {
  "upcoming": [
    {
      "id": "17",
      "date": "2018/04/23 13:25",
      "title": "Team A"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "date": "2018/04/23 13:25",
      "title": "Team B"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "date": "2019/06/16 21:45",
      "title": "Team c"
    }
  ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Match : Codable {
    let id: String
    let date: String
    let title: String
}

struct Matches : Codable {
    let upcoming: [Match]
}

do {
    let matches = try JSONDecoder().decode(Matches.self, from:jsonData)
    print(matches.upcoming.count)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Now your `matches.upcoming` are your model array and using it as a `TableView` datasource is really straightforward.